# C# modal window. How to Implement behaviour to add and remove Polinomials from Main View

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

;)
I am currently developing an WPF application which main function is to draw polynomials in a view.
So I have my main Window with a canvas and a child Modal Window where I can set the parameters for the polynomial, and also a listbox listing all the previous polynomials.When I press the OK button, modal window closes and in the main window my code looks like this:

```
        PanelParametros pn = new PanelParametros();
        pn.Owner = this;
        pn.ShowDialog();
        Polynomial p= new Polynomial();

       if (pn.DialogResult == true)
        {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pn.boxA.Text))
            {
                valueA = float.Parse(pn.boxA.Text);
            }
       p.setvalueA(valueA); 
       // ..... //
      //Set the rest of parameters to my p object
```

Problem I find is how to distinguish when I press the OK button just after adding a new Polynomial and when I just removed some polynomials from my ListBox.

Because the way now it's coded every time I press the OK button I create an instance of a Polynomial object and sometimes this is not what I want.

Thanks in advance and Merry Christmas to all programmers in the world haha!

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a Cancel button in the modal form and explicitely check "pn.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK" to detect that OK was actually pressed. If the modal form was left via cancel, nothing happens in your main form.

Another approach would be to remember the most recently displayed polynomial and only redraw if some change can be detected. This could be done by calculating a hash sum across all polynomial parameters. Only if the hash sum changes, a redraw makes sense.